# SASS is not compiling the appropriate CSS

Tags: css, sass

I am getting some non-sensical output from sass regarding these few lines.

```
@mixin full_shadow($size, $color){
  text-shadow : $size 0 0 $color, -$size 0 0 $color, 0 $size 0 $color, 0 -$size 0 $color;
}

p {
  @include full_shadow(1.25px, red);
}
```

Here's what is weird

```
p { /* Expected Output */
  text-shadow: 1.25px 0 0 red, -1.25px 0 0 red, 0 1.25px 0 red, 0 -1.25px 0 red;
}

p { /* SASS Output*/
  text-shadow: 1.25px 0 0 red, -1.25px 0 0 red, 0 1.25px 0 red, -1.25px 0 red;
}
```

It's not immediately obvious, but the SASS output is missing a term at the very end of the property assignment.

`... , -$size 0 $color;` does not equal the defined `..., 0 -$size 0 $color;`

Any insight on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I think what's happening is sass is seeing "0 -1.25" and doing math on it. Does it work if you do `0 #{-1 * $size}` ?

Comment: @jack, you're right (many thanks!). I decided to go with parenthesis over  `#{...}` for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s being interpreted as a subtraction: `0 - $size`. Use parentheses to force unary minus:

```
0 (-$size) 0 $color
```

Comment: That would make perfect sense, Thanks!